# PHP: return message 'You have to answer all questions'

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML list of 30 questions, which have to answer all. On Submit an echo gives a result-text according to the answer which was chosen. But the problem is, if a user doesn´t fill all questions, an message have to display: 'You have to answer all questions' on the question page, and the user doesn´t have to be forwarded to the result page.
How I can manage this?

Thanks

Follwing code I set:

HTML page (question page)

```
<div class="Fragen1">   
    <li>
    <p>Kannst du dir vorstellen Kinder zu haben?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="1-q1" value="A" >Ja, auf jeden Fall.</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="1-q1" value="B" >Ich bin mir noch unsicher.</label>
    </li>
</div>
```

PHP page (result page)

```
<?php
if($_GET['Senden'] == true) {
     if($_GET['1-q1'] == "A") {
         echo 'Das ist Antwort A';
     }
     if($_GET['1-q1'] == "B") {
         echo 'Das ist Antwort B';
     }
     if($_GET['1-q1'] == "") {
         echo 'Keine Eingabe';
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Either check client-side using javascript or allow the form to be submitted and if there are no errors/ommissions redirect using `header('Location: results.php');` etc???

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 have a new attribute called "required".

So:

```
<div class="Fragen1">   
    <li>
    <p>Kannst du dir vorstellen Kinder zu haben?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="1-q1" value="A" required>Ja, auf jeden Fall.</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="1-q1" value="B" required>Ich bin mir noch unsicher.</label>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quickly answer, I will try. But how I can define, where the message appears on the question page, which code I need for this?

Comment: the input will appear in red, and the focus of mouse will be pointed on the missing target